# webflow smooth scroll bug chrome

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling, webflow

I use this Smooth-scroll script:

http://smooth-scroll-32e0f4.webflow.io/

It **works**, but Google Chrome displaying error **for every wheel move**:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive.

How can i fix it?

Or maybe you can advise me another script to use...

I use it on this site: http://adlook.anarchy.monster/

Answer (score 0):

Oh! My problem is already fixed here:

> [cdnjs.com/libraries/smoothscroll](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/smoothscroll)